# Custom NSFont picker menu

Tags: macos, cocoa

Instead of using NSFont Panel

[image]

to pick a font for my text view. I'm trying to build a custom set of pop up buttons to select the font family and then the font sub type.

[image]

My question is, when i have an NSTextView with some text, i can right click on the text to open the font panel and changes to the panel are applied to the textView automatically. How can i achieve this behavior with my custom implementation? I believe there is some fiddling that has to be done with NSFontManager.shared i've tried

`NSFontManager.shared.setSelectedFont(font, isMultiple: false)
  textView.changeFont(NSFontManager.shared)`

I've a work around by applying the selected fonts, and size to the NSAttributedString of the textView textStorage, however this feels like a hack.

Comment: send changeFont: to your textview - this is correct. Also NSFontManager.shared.setSelectedFont is correct. Any issues with those 2 lines? You can see this by using breakpoint command (lldb) br set -n "changeFont:" After try to change font using fontpanel and breakpoint is hit

Answer (score 1):

idk if this is best way to do this but it works

```
      textView.usesFontPanel = true
      NSFontManager.shared.fontPanel(true)?.setPanelFont(font, isMultiple: false)
      NSFontManager.shared.modifyFontViaPanel(self)
```